# Переменная неправильно передается в функцию

Tags: javascript

Любые числа кроме тех что начинаются на ноль передаются правильно. Как такое вообще возможно?

```js
function descendingOrder(n){
    console.log(n);
}
descendingOrder(0123);
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB_%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Восьмеричные числа](https://zametkinapolyah.ru/veb-programmirovanie/zametki-po-javascript/tipy-dannyx-v-javascript-chisla-javascript-chislo-javascript-preobrazovanie-chisel-v-drugie-tipy-dannyx.html) в JavaScript поддерживаются, но не всеми
> реализациями. Восьмеричное число в JavaScript начинается с 0, после
> чего следуют цифры от 0 до 7.
>
> ```
> 0123
>  
> 0432
>  
> 0347
> ```
>
> Избегайте записывать целые числа в JavaScript в восьмеричной системе
> счисления, поскольку никто точно не скажет, поддерживаются ли в данной
> реализации восьмеричные целые числа.

0123 (в восьмеричной) = 83 (в десятичной)